# Django UUIDField issue

Tags: python, django, uuid

I am trying to get the UUIDField to work in python django using the following model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

However when I try adding an instance of the model to the database it returns the following error: 
TypeError at /tickets/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UUID found

The documentation of UUIDField is really short and doesn't really help me.

edit: I did import uuid and here is the full traceback:
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tickets/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'events',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  48.         return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  663.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  228.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  603.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  461.                 ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_representation
  356.         name = self.get_name(value)
File "/Users/daviddejong/.virtualenvs/restDemo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in get_name
  276.         return six.text_type(obj)

Exception Type: TypeError at /tickets/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UUID found
```

Edit 2: My serializer looks like this:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name')
```

Edit 3:

I found the error. I made a mistake in my model. My unicode looked like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

And of course this does not work.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You have added 'import uuid' in your project ? Please add entire traceback.

Comment: There is maybe a problem in your Django REST framework serializer. Do you use the `serializers.UUIDField()` for your ids?

Comment: I added my serializer

Comment: @icam0 consider adding your resolution as an answer and accept it to resolve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```